# Unknown user defined function in snowpark scala

Tags: scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowpark. I have one spark-scala project. I am migrating to snowpark scala. I have this udf in my project

```
def maskColumnsUDF(maskChar : String = "*", noOfLeftVisibleChars : Int = 1, noOfRightVisiblechars : Int = 1): UserDefinedFunction = udf((attrVal :String) => {

      var finalString =  ""
      if(attrVal == null){ attrVal }
      else if (attrVal.length > 4 ) {
        val attrArray = attrVal.toCharArray
        for (counter <- 0 to attrArray.length() - 1) {
          if (counter < noOfLeftVisibleChars || counter > attrArray.length() - (noOfRightVisiblechars + 1){
            finalString = finalString + attrArray(counter)
          }
          else {
            finalString = finalString + maskChar
          }
        }
        finalString
      }
      else { "***" }
})
```

When i am calling the udf :

```
columnNamesList.foreach(columnName => {
    sampleDf = sampleDf.withColumn(columnName+"_zs_masked",
    UserDefinedFunctions.maskColumnsUDF("*",1,1)(col(columnName)))
})
```

I am  getting this error

[main] ERROR com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection - Failed to analyze schema of query:
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: Unknown user-defined function SNOWPARK_TEST.PUBLIC.SNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_GICGX7MLYN3OHZO

I even tried simple udf like this

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("column_name", StringType, nullable = false),
    StructField("featureName", StringType, nullable = false),
    StructField("distribution", DoubleType, nullable = false)
  ))

val data = Seq(
    Row("A", "foo", 0.2),
    Row("A", "bar", 0.5),
    Row("B", "baz", 0.1),
    Row("B", "qux", 0.3)
)

var featureDF: DataFrame = session.createDataFrame(data, schema)
featureDF = featureDF.withColumn("test_udf", UserDefinedFunctions.test_udf(col("column_name")))
```

getting this

[main] ERROR com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection - failed to execute query:
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
Unknown user-defined function SNOWPARK_TEST.PUBLIC.SNOWPARK_TEMP_FUNCTION_R0KRMUFIRRFYNUX

I haven't added the sql query it is trying to execute in both cases because the queries were too long

Answer (score 1):

I tried some code similar to waht you had.
I even created a test scala proc like this:

```scala
create procedure test_proc()
    returns string
    language scala
    runtime_version = 2.12
    packages =('com.snowflake:snowpark:latest')
    handler = 'Procedure.main'
    as '

import com.snowflake.snowpark._
import com.snowflake.snowpark.types._
import com.snowflake.snowpark.functions._

object Procedure {
  def main(session: Session): String = {
    import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, PrintStream}
    val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    Console.withOut(new PrintStream(outputStream)) {
        def maskColumnsUDF(maskChar : String = "*", noOfLeftVisibleChars : Int = 1, noOfRightVisiblechars : Int = 1): UserDefinedFunction = udf((attrVal :String) => {        
              var finalString =  ""
              if(attrVal == null){ attrVal }
              else if (attrVal.length > 4 ) {
                val attrArray = attrVal.toCharArray
                for (counter <- 0 to attrArray.length() - 1) {
                  if (counter < noOfLeftVisibleChars || counter > attrArray.length() - (noOfRightVisiblechars + 1))
                  {
                    finalString = finalString + attrArray(counter)
                  }
                  else {
                    finalString = finalString + maskChar
                  }
                }
                finalString
              }
              else { "***" }
        })
        
        val schema = StructType(Seq(
            StructField("column_name", StringType, nullable = false),
            StructField("featureName", StringType, nullable = false),
            StructField("distribution", DoubleType, nullable = false)
          ))
    
        val data = Seq(
            Row("A", "foo", 0.2),
            Row("A", "bar", 0.5),
            Row("B", "baz", 0.1),
            Row("B", "qux", 0.3)
        )
        
        var featureDF: DataFrame = session.createDataFrame(data, schema)
        featureDF.withColumn("xx",maskColumnsUDF("*",1,1)(col("column_name"))).show()
    }
    outputStream.toString()
  }
}';
```

And it works fine.
Because this are temp UDFs what I think you might be facing is that you are using different sessions, that is why you are getting the error that the function does not exist.

You can try something like:

```
def maskColumnsUDF(session:Session,maskChar : String = "*", noOfLeftVisibleChars : Int = 1, noOfRightVisiblechars : Int = 1): 
    UserDefinedFunction = {
        val udf_name = s"maskColumnsUDF_${noOfLeftVisibleChars}_${noOfRightVisiblechars}"
        session.sql(s"drop function if exists ${udf_name}(varchar)")
        session.udf.registerPermanent(
         udf_name,
         (attrVal :String) => {        
              var finalString =  ""
              if(attrVal == null){ attrVal }
              else if (attrVal.length > 4 ) {
                val attrArray = attrVal.toCharArray
                for (counter <- 0 to attrArray.length() - 1) {
                  if (counter < noOfLeftVisibleChars || counter > attrArray.length() - (noOfRightVisiblechars + 1))
                  {
                    finalString = finalString + attrArray(counter)
                  }
                  else {
                    finalString = finalString + maskChar
                  }
                }
                finalString
              }
              else { "***" }
        },"@mystage")
    }
```

That will use permanent UDFs which should work in all session. I just recommend for diagnosing the error. It will be better to determine if the sessions are different.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In whole of the project , I am creating only one session. I'll try this permanent register approach.